# All subsets in Subset_sum_problem

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm stuck at solving [Subset_sum_problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Given a set of integers(S), need to compute non-empty subsets whose sum is equal to a given target(T).

**Example**:
Given set, S{4, 8, 10, 16, 20, 22}
Target, T = 52.

**Constraints**:
The number of elements N of set S is limited to 8. Hence a NP time solution is acceptable as N has a small upperbound.
Time and space complexities are not really a concern.

**Output**:

Possible subsets with sum exactly equal to T=52 are:

{10, 20, 22}

{4, 10, 16, 22}

The solution given in Wiki and in some other pages tries to check whether there exists such a subset or not (YES/NO).

It doesn't really help to compute all possible subsets as outlined in the above example.

The dynamic programming approach at this [link](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS3343/dp/subsetsum.html) gives single such subset ***but I need all such subsets.***

One obvious approach is to compute all 2^N combinations using brute force but that would be my last resort.

I'm looking for some programmatic example(preferably C++) or algorithm which computes such subsets with illutrations/examples?

Comment: If you are not worried about space/time complexity, why is enumerating all sets so bad?

Comment: What is the upper bound? Constraints?

Comment: Hi Knoothe, I may have to enumerate it for several such targets. Hence, would like something better than brute force.

Comment: If you have several such targets (but same array), then enumerating is even better! You get all the possible targets in one shot! So you just enumerate once (per array).

Comment: Hi ritesh_nitw, N has an upper cap of 8 (which means a given set may have a max of 8 elements, this is the only constraint.

Comment: @Arun: To be clear,  you can enumerate once, and for each possible target store the list of subsets. You can use a hashtable (keyed on the target) with a list of 8 bit integers (to denote each set) for the value. Next time you get a target query, just lookup the hashtable and return the list.

Comment: @Knoothe, thanks a lot for all your valuable inputs. Especially "8 bit integers (to denote each set)" is a good idea :)

Comment: You are welcome. The 8 bit integer to denote set is a well known trick (I believe others have mentioned that in their answers too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct the dynamic-programming table for the subset sum problem you intialize most of it like so (taken from the Wikipedia article referenced in the question):

Q(i,s) := Q(i − 1,s) or (xi == s) or Q(i − 1,s − xi)

This sets the table element to 0 or 1.

This simple formula doesn't let you distinguish between those several cases that can give you 1.

But you can instead set the table element to a value that'd let you distinguish those cases, something like this:

Q(i,s) := {Q(i − 1,s) != 0} *** 1** + {xi == s} *** 2** + {Q(i − 1,s − xi) != 0} ***4**

Then you can traverse the table from the last element. At every element the element value will tell you whether you have zero, one or two possible paths from it and their directions. All paths will give you all combinations of numbers summing up to T. And that's at most 2<sup>N</sup>.

Comment: Good idea! Thanx Alexey Frunze!

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze please elaborate how do i get all the subsets? I have the matrix, but can't figure out how to use it for generating all possible subsets. Also say if for the base case i.e. for (i == 1) Q(i, s) should be (xi == s) or 2 * (xi == s)?

Comment: @shivshnkr A subset is a path through non-zero Q(i,s) cells, just like in the classical single-solution case described in the article. If you compute Q(i,s) as I suggest, then at each cell Q(i,s) the current path may fork into several paths. You look at the bits set in Q(i,s) and from there you know where to go next, to which cell(s).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze http://codepad.org/47B9vJMe please look at the matrix and tell where to start and how to get the path, what path should i choose say if Q(i, s) = 5 or 4?

Comment: @shivshnkr I'm afraid, you need to understand how the DP algorithm explained in the Wikipedia article works first, as it seems to me that currently you don't but if you did, you wouldn't have asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

if N <= 8 why don't just go with 2^n solution?? it's only 256 possibilities that will be very fast

Comment: even if N=30, it's still doable within 1 second

Comment: @Mike T & marcadian, In a way I'm leaning more towards brute force :)

Answer (score 1):

Just brute force it. If N is limited to 8, your total number of subsets is 2^8, which is only 256. They give constraints for a reason.

You can express the set inclusion as a binary string where each element is either in the set or out of the set. Then you can just increment your binary string (which can simply be represented as an integer) and then determine which elements are in the set or not using the bitwise & operator. Once you've counted up to 2^N, you know you've gone through all possible subsets.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is using a dynamic programming approach.However, dynamic programming just answers whether a subset sum exits or not as you mentioned in your question.

By dynamic programming, you can output all the solutions by backtracking.However, the overall time complexity to generate all the valid combinations is still 2^n.

So, any better algorithm than 2^n is close to impossible.

**UPD**:
From @Knoothe Comment:
You can modify [horowitz-sahni's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Exponential_time_algorithm) algorithm to enumerate all possible subsets.If there are `M` such sets whose sum equals `S`, then overall time complexity is in `O(N * 2^(N/2) + MN)`

Comment: @Knoothe: How? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Lookup horowitz sahni's subset sum algorithm, which is O(sqrt(2^n)) (i.e. O(2^(n/2))) (I might be missing a factor of n).

Comment: @Knoothe:After reading the following Talks:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ASubset_sum_problem#Horowitz_and_Sahni , still not sure whether horowitz sahini's is better than DP.

Comment: I wasn't comparing against DP. I was just disputing the claim: "Better than 2^n is close to impossible". You can modify horowitz-sahni's algorithm to enumerate all possible subsets (say there are m such sets) in O(n * 2^(n/2) + mn) time.

Comment: You are welcome :-) btw, I suggest you not link to Talk:, as those are just some discussions between random folks who are debating the edit of the main wiki page of subset sum. I believe the main wiki page of subset sum has a mention of the algorithm and you should link to that.